# Bind SSH to my PC

Tags: networking, 18.04, ssh

I have 2 PCs running 18.04. I SSH into one from another using `Terminal`. Say from A to B. Is it possible to make sure that an SSH is possible only from `system A`, my main machine ? Would be great to know how.

I do it only one way. ie, only from A to B. Never had the need to SSH from `system B` into `system A`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A very, very simple approach could be:

- Add the following lines to your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

`ListenAddress [IP of HostB]
AllowUsers [User of HostA@IP of HostA]`

- Reload you SSH Service `sudo systemctl reload sshd`

Comment: Thanks. I will check. could you please the 2 command with a sample ID and IP. I am not sure which part of it should be replaced. Say, `ListenAddress [192.168.1.115]`  `AllowUsers [james@192.168.1.117]`.

Comment: Sure, the lines should read something like `ListenAddress 10.0.0.1` and `AllowUsers user1@10.0.0.2`. I don't have the means to test this at the moment, so please make sure that no other user can actually connect.

Comment: Thanks. Is this better than private key, public key method ?

Comment: No, it is not, but it also depends on the scenario. If this is a ssh server which needs to accessible from the internet, I would disable root login, enforce publickey authentication, disable password/empty password authentication and restrict access to the ssh service by means of a VPN and Firewall.

For simple testing purposes on your LAN, enforcing publickey authentication, disabling password/empty password authentication and root login should be more than enough

Comment: Thanks. Just wanted to know :)